# Hugo nested menus: adding partial for menu.html

Tags: html, hugo

I'm using the Hugo Justice theme for my web site and have trouble implementing nested menus. The main menu items appear, but not the nested menus (nor the down arrow indicating there are sub-menus.)

In ../layouts/partial I have menu.html, but I don't know where I need to include that file. The current development site code is available at https://github.com/rs-aesi/my-company-website.git.

I'm not a professional web site developer but have maintained my own company's html/css site for several decades. Now I need to replace it with additional value so I need to learn how to do this with Hugo.

All help appreciated.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your GitHub repo, it appears that you have the Justice theme in the `themes` directory, but also a lot of partials are also in the site `layouts` directory, which overrides the justice directory, and will probably cause conflicts and make your site difficult to maintain.

The menu.html partial should be called using the command `{{ partial "menu" . }}`. You can put this command either in a page template in the _default directory, or in another partial such as `site-header.html` or `page-header.html`.